# Short story about aliens that routinely kill their wives? Who wrote it?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Story about astronauts who landed on an alien planet. The aliens would corral all the female aliens in a pen. The males would take on a new alien wife every month (year?) and kill the old wife. The astronauts decide to help the females. The females rebel and kill the astronauts saying they threatened their way of life. Who wrote it? Title? Read as a child....think it was a short story in a book with many other stories.

Comment: Can you add *when* you read it, as in elaborate on *when you were a child*?

Comment: About 30+ years ago... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is "The Monsters", by Robert Sheckley. It's the lead story in the collection "[Store of the Worlds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590174941)" as well as appearing in [a few other places](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58569).

> 'Shall we go down and have a closer look?’ Hum asked.
>
> ‘All right. I think we have time — wait! What day is this?’
>
> Hum calculated silently, then said, ‘The fifth day of Luggat.’
>
> 'Damn,’ Cordovir said. ‘I have to go home and kill my wife.’
>
> 'It’s a few hours before sunset,’ Hum said. ‘I think you have time to do both.’

Comment: Yea! Thank you!!!! :)

Comment: Husbands always forgetting to do the chores on time lol

Comment: Yes! So true!! Lol :)